# How to create a validation for only certain ages java

Tags: java, validation, constructor

I need to write a validation that validates a persons age.  The age can only be 20, 30, or 40.  When I create the below method and try and create a person object that is age 30, i get the illegal argument exception.  Any ideas why?

```
  private static void validateAge(final int age) {

    if (age != 20 || age != 30 || age != 40 ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid age " + age);
    }

}
```

Comment: You need `AND`, not `OR`: `if (age != 20 && age != 30 && age != 40 ) throw ...`. Alternatively, `if (!(age == 20 || age == 30 || age == 40 )) throw ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the only legal values are  20, 30, or 40. 
This means:
 `age == 20 || age == 30 || age == 40` which negated is
 `age != 20 && age != 30 && age != 40`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        
        int age = 20;
        
        boolean isValid = isValidAge(age);
        
        if(isValid)
            System.out.println("Entered Age is Valid.");
        else
            System.out.println("Entered Age is InValid.");
    }
    
    private static boolean isValidAge(final int age){
        if(age != 20 && age != 30 && age != 40)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to check if that age is among 20,30,40 ;if not exception is thrown .

```
     if  ( ! ( age==20  ||  age==30  ||  age==40 ) ) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid age " + age);
}
```

The above condition must be used to check whether age is among those three values .

The condition you used will always throws exception because at least one condition will be true and result will turn out to be true in case of Logical OR as a single value of age will not match with every condition.

If we take 30;   age!=20 and age!=40 will be true so result is true and exception is thrown even if 30 is present.

But in this case age==30 is true so overall condition is false as negation is applied so exception is not thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to use **AND** operator than **OR** , So you can check the conditions you have.
while you are using **OR**  in some cases (in your example of object value 30)
the condition will be true , so the other conditions wont matter as this is **OR**
so the exception is thrown.

so you can replace your if condition as,

```
if(age != 20 && age != 30 && age != 40)
```